# A visual indicator for counting bars in 4/4

Tags: time-signatures

I am helping a colleague out with a basic project. The project simply records bars tapped in a 4/4 time signature. There are two dynamic elements here. A beat indicator (in the screenshot, these are the 16 bars, 3 of which are filled in), and a bar counter (194 Bars Tapped). The Tap Beat button simply counts the beat.

Now my colleague and I are having a discrepancy with the visual elements. When should that bar counter increase to 195?! Once the 4th block is filled in? or once the first block in the NEXT bar is filled in? He says once the 4th block is filled in... I say once the first block in the next bar is filled in.

**Additionally, do you feel there is ANY benefit to the visual element of the 16 blocks filling in?**

*If any of the above is confusing, please let me know and I will do my best to clarify further. Thank you.*

[image: When should 194 change to 195?]

Comment: What is the purpose of the visual indicator?

Answer (score 1):

In a musical score bars begin to be counted at 1, there is no "measure 0". The first note of a piece is said to be in beat 1 of measure 1 (well, not when you have anacrusis, but that's not the issue here). 
So if you wish to have consistency with the music notation convention I would say your friend is right, but you should change the caption to "Tapping bar #x" instead of "x-1 bars tapped", and start counting from 1.

Comment: It may be better to show the number of bars *and beats* tapped. This is commonly done with text notation like 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 for the beats of bar 1. Unless the music is *always* in 4-bar phrases (which is probably too restrictive even for some "pop" music), what is the purpose of having groups of 4 and 16 bars in the graphics display?